# Is the perfmon2 tool obsolete due to the same functionality being included in the current Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring, perf

I was having some issues with the PAPI tool and multiplex and this answer by the PAPI creator led me to check out perfmon2: 
http://lists.eecs.utk.edu/pipermail/ptools-perfapi/2008-April/000900.html

But further researching led me to believe the perf subsystem has been natively included in the linux kernel since version 2.6.31.

My question is, is this correct? 
and if so, do I need to install "perf" to have the advantages of this subsystem?

I'm wondering if PAPI is really using the subsystem or if it needs perf (I'm guessing no, since there's nothing about perf in the documentation).

The reason I'm not installing perf before asking is because I already have some results and I don't want to alter the state of the system unless necesary.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 with kernel 3.13.0.